# Simple routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Total noob question.

I am building a simple photoblog in Rails which consists of Posts. Each post has its own id "/posts/1". I built Posts using rails scaffolding.

The problem is that I am unable to go to a url such as "/posts/index" or "/posts/anything" because it's trying to match anything after "/posts/" it to an id... So I get back an error like:

```
Couldn't find Post with ID=index
```

I'm sure this could be fixed with routes, but I'm not really sure how and I feel that there is some big-picture problem I am missing here.

You can clone my app from here: https://github.com/tbhockey/PhotoBlog

Thank you.

Comment: can you show us your routes ?

Comment: (not sure how to make a comment render as code...)

Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  
  root :to => "home#index"

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end

Comment: ahh, so you have the generic route (you can just edit your post to show this code if you like)

Comment: Hm, that didn't seem to work. But maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. My objective is for "/posts" to display the posts and then to have something like "/posts/archive" display a condensed history of all posts made.

Perhaps "archive" should have it's own separate controller and view rather than living under "post"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `rake routes` is usually pretty helpful.  In this case, the route to your index should just be /posts (not /posts/index).  If you run `rake routes` you'll probably see something like

```
posts GET    /posts(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
```

That's trying to tell you that the URL /posts will be directed to the index action of your posts_controller.  Also, this may be referred to in your code as `posts_path` or `posts_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this for your routes.rb :

```
  scope :path => '/posts', :controller => :posts do
    get 'show/(:id)' => :show, :as => 'show_post'
  end
```

For a /posts/show/1, it will call the show action of the posts controller.

It's always a nice idea to learn about how routing works in Rails. It's very important and will help you understand many things about Rails. Especially looking at named routes is vital for good Rails programming.